# Two apps on Apache server with URI

Tags: apache, uri, virtualhost, domain-name, apache2.2

I need to install a server with Apache 2.2 on Linux and I need to do two VirtualHosts differentiated by URI.

But with only one domain name and one ip address. And I can't use Alias.

I tried something like that but that doesn't work :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
    ServerName localhost/app1
    ServerAlias www.localhost/app1

    <Directory /var/www/app1>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app2
    ServerName localhost/app2
    ServerAlias www.localhost/app2

    <Directory /var/www/app2>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You cannot use VirtualHosts if you have only a single domain name and only a single ip address. you can put the apps into subfolders of the sole DocumentRoot, so that the apps are addressed by an url ending in the apps folder name. That is a well known scheme. but since there is nothing for apache to decide which VirtualHost to use you cannot rely on that feature. Note, that a server name is not a path.

Comment: We can't to do something with the server path?

Comment: Not towards a Virtualhost, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to the first answer here, it's working : https://serverfault.com/questions/588841/two-apps-on-apache-server-with-uri

I put the answer here if one day the link doesn't work :

What you could do is set up a reverse proxy to different virtual hosts listening only on loopback.

You would get in your www.localhost virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost

    ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://webapp1.local/
    ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://webapp2.local/
</Virtualhost>
```

And create two virtualhosts for the apps:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
    ServerName webapp1.local

    <Directory /var/www/app1>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app2
    ServerName webapp2.local

    <Directory /var/www/app2>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Make sure to add webapp1.local and webapp2.local to your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score -2):

Since you have only a single domain name and only a single ip address available there is no means for the apache server to distinguish which host is meant. Therefore there is noo sense in defining VirtualHosts here.

However you certainly can place two apps in separate folders inside your DocumentRoot:

```
ServerName whatever-your-domain.is

DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www/app1>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/app2>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then you'd call those apps by their paths:

- apps1: http://whatever-your-domain.is/app1
- apps2: http://whatever-your-domain.is/app2

Don't forget to take care of requests to the "main folder" of that single host: `/var/www` which can be reached by http://whatever-your-domain.is/

Comment: Yes, but if I but just the document Root, I can to do that too. But here I can put only one error.log for the two paths. It's for that I need two VirtualHost

Comment: Sorry, but you simply cannot use VirtualHosts because of the requirements you posted. Since apache allows only one error log file per host you are limited to a single log file as long as you rely on apaches core features. You might however want to take a log at the log config module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html